# Client API lookup field: LookupId has a value but LookupValue is null

Tags: lookup-column

I'm doing something very similar to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/how-to-retrieve-lookup-values-using-clientcontext) question; trying to get the value of a lookup field using the Sharepoint .NET client API.  I can get the Id, but not the value.  For some reason, the value is always null.

```
item["Company"]
// Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
```

And this:

```
((FieldLookupValue)item["Company"]).LookupId;
// 3334
```

But then this:

```
((FieldLookupValue)item["Company"]).LookupValue;
// null
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: While writing this I figured out the problem was permissions, I'll write an answer in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sharepoint App needs permissions to the list used in the lookup column as well as the list you're querying or it can only retrieve the ID and not the name.