# Unable to show the lookup field in datagrid view using CSOM sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, lookup-column, gridview

```
private void btnGetdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        try
        {
            
            string WebUrl = this.listUrl.Text;
            string lib = this.txtLib.Text;


            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(WebUrl))
            {
                string login = "login id";
                string password = "password";
                var securePassword = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c in password)
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                }

                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
                
                
                List SDlist = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(lib);

                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                ListItemCollection items = SDlist.GetItems(query);
            
                
                FieldCollection efields = SDlist.Fields;
               

               
                ctx.Load(items);
                
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                
                if (items.Count != 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    DataRow dRow;

                    DataColumn dcID = new DataColumn("Id");
                    dcID.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

                    DataColumn dcTitle = new DataColumn("Title");
                    dcTitle.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

                    DataColumn dcFname = new DataColumn("FirstName");
                    dcFname.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

                    DataColumn dcLastName = new DataColumn("LastName");
                    dcLastName.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

                    DataColumn dcEmpid = new DataColumn("Empid");
                    dcEmpid.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

                    DataColumn dcCourse_x0020_offered = new DataColumn("Course_x0020_offered");
                    dcCourse_x0020_offered.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");


                    dt.Columns.Add(dcID);
                    dt.Columns.Add(dcTitle);
                    dt.Columns.Add(dcFname);
                    dt.Columns.Add(dcLastName);
                    dt.Columns.Add(dcEmpid);
                    dt.Columns.Add(dcCourse_x0020_offered);


                    foreach (ListItem item in items)
                    {
                        dRow = dt.NewRow();                         
                        dRow["Id"] = item.Id;
                        dRow["Title"] = item["Title"];
                        dRow["FirstName"] = item["FirstName"];
                        dRow["LastName"] = item["LastName"];
                        dRow["Empid"] = item["Empid"];

                        dRow["Course_x0020_offered"] =item["Course_x0020_offered"];//lookup column

                            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
                        }
```

How can I get the lookup column data in the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
FieldLookupValue courseOffered = item["Course_x0020_offered"] as FieldLookupValue;

if (courseOffered != null) {
    dRow["Course_x0020_offered"] = courseOffered.LookupValue;
} else {
    dRow["Course_x0020_offered"] = "";
}
```

**References**:

1. [How to retrieve lookup values using ClientContext?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/how-to-retrieve-lookup-values-using-clientcontext)
2. [Get\Set value for lookup field using client object model SharePoint 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/96a20ee3-adfd-473c-b1bf-c1e22f22242e/getset-value-for-lookup-field-using-client-object-model-sharepoint-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: Sorry for typo. check updated answer, it should be `courseOffered`.